# Start with web API/REST API

Tags: rest, asp.net-web-api

I am in the process of creating an app (cross-platform with [Ionic](http://ionicframework.com/) framework) and during my research about app with this framework I found the one created for [HabitRPG](https://habitrpg.com/) and it is using an API to retrieve data, it totally suits my app as well, but I don't know where to start to create an API nor what to use.

I allready did some quick test with **Spring**, **NodeJS** and **Symfony** (with *FOS*) but I'm looking for something really easy to use and to setup but still to have a lot of flexibility (like manage security, users, and data visibility).

Is there a specific technology easy enough to start with ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create a Web API and host it, you can perhaps have the look at APISpark (http://restlet.com/products/apispark/). It's an online plateform that allows to design your APIs following REST principles and then host them. The data are also managed by the platform.

Hope it helps.
Thierry

Comment: It seems to be a really good product unfortunately I can't use services like that but have to make my own (it's a School Project). Anyway by digging more with nodeJS I found [Loopback](http://loopback.io/) which seems to be really what I am looking for. But I keep your link in mind for my future project :)

Comment: Okay I understand well! ;-) There is a free linked product that can help you. It's called Restlet Studio (http://restlet.com/products/restlet-studio/) and it also to design your API and gets corresponding Swagger2 structure. You can then use either the tool to generate server skeleton or use swagger-codegen to generate similar things. A lot of technologies are supported there. Hope it helps you.